# Read Pattern Scan c++ Access violation reading memory

Tags: readprocessmemory

FindPattern Function looks like this

```
DWORD FindPattern(DWORD base ,char *module, char *pattern, char *mask)
{
    MODULEINFO mInfo = GetModuleInfo(module);
    DWORD size = (DWORD)mInfo.SizeOfImage;
    DWORD patternLength = (DWORD)strlen(mask);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < size - patternLength; i++)
    {
        bool found = true;
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < patternLength; j++)
        {
            found &= mask[j] == '?' || pattern[j] == *(char*)(base + i + j);
        }
        if (found)
        {
            return base + i;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

and i'm using use the function like this

```
DWORD aAddy = FindPattern(BaseAddress,(char*)("ros.exe"),
                const_cast<LPSTR>("\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\0x88\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFA\x44\x00\x00\x00\x3F\x00\x00\x00\x00"),
                const_cast<LPSTR>("???????????????x??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????xx???x????"));
```

while debugging i got error on j = 15 and mask[j] = 'x'
the exception thrown show access violation reading location "base"

can someone help me what is wrong with j = 15 or i just wrong passing the parameters?

i cant pass the char* mode just like ("ros.exe") its give me error 
cant convert argumen char* to char*.

Answer (score 1):

Gee that code looks familiar :P

You get Access Violation on 'base' because you do not have read permissions on 'BaseAddress' which you pass in as the 'base' argument.  We do not know what 'BaseAddress' is because you don't include how you assign the value of that variable in the code you posted.  Perhaps it is uninitialized or you need to use VirtualProtect() to get read permissions.  I would assume you don't initialize it or are passing in the wrong address.

It reads from 'base' the first time when j=15 because this is the first element of the char array that is not a wildcard, meaning your code doesn't read from 'base + i + j' until a non-wildcard is found that is why it doesn't happen until j=15.

The original source code includes this line to get the base address of the module, but you have modified/removed it.

```
 DWORD base = (DWORD)mInfo.lpBaseOfDll;
```

Alternatively you can use this to get the base address of the executable

```
 DWORD base = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

Once you properly define base I think your code will work just fine