# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when scanning for a pattern in a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, pattern-matching, access-violation

I'm trying to scan for a pattern to a function I found using IDA Pro, but every time I try to use FindPattern I get an ACCESS_VIOLATION_EXCEPTION on the first loop.

FindPattern Func:

```
DWORD FindPattern(char* module, char* pattern, char* mask)
{
    MODULEINFO mInfo = GetModuleInfo(module);
    DWORD base = (DWORD)mInfo.lpBaseOfDll;
    DWORD size = (DWORD)mInfo.SizeOfImage;
    DWORD patternLength = (DWORD)strlen(mask);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < size - patternLength; i++)
    {
        bool found = true;
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < patternLength; j++)
        {
            found &= mask[j] == '?' || pattern[j] == *(char*)(base + i + j);
        }
        if (found)
        {
            return base + i;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Use of the function:

```
    DWORD ScannedAddress = FindPattern((char*)("Program.exe"), 
        const_cast<LPSTR>("\x40\x56\x57\x41\x56\x48\x81\xEC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\xC7\x44\x24\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x89\x9C\x24\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x8B\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x33\xC4\x48\x89\x84\x24\x00\x00\x00\x00\x49\x8B\xF0"), 
        const_cast<LPSTR>("xxxxxxxx????xxxx?????xxxx????xxx????xxxxxxx????xxx"));
```

I'm relatively new to C++ so I'm trying my best here, but not sure what I messed up. Only thing I can see is this warning from VS, but I read that it's just a bug in VS2019 (https://theentirecirc.us/9b62f53eabae6ba32efab72b95738c66.png (Apparently can't inline image because you need reputation)).

Exception Details: https://theentirecirc.us/69d9d52935432cc7b836f2fed504b59f.png

At the point of the exception both `i` and `j` are 0. (https://theentirecirc.us/8c1909ef75ed2cddc285ad9f45186254.png)

I then want to reroute this function using MinHook, to change the return value, but I can't seem to get the Pattern Scan working in the first place

Comment: C-style cast from pointer to 32 bit integer (and back) is obviously not good. You should really try writing without casts here... VS adds those squiggly lines and warns you for a reason.

Comment: If you're talking about the const_casts, that's something I found on code from a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149035/read-pattern-scan-c-access-violation-reading-memory), so I decided to try it, didn't make a difference. Before I was defining all the arguments as char[] and then using them in the function, using them directly didn't work even though I have character set as multi-byte.

Comment: Where does it crash? The debugger tells you.

Comment: It crashes here: https://theentirecirc.us/523498a5be68510661a9a3f8e9ade91f.png

Comment: Not really sure what the duplication is referencing, the "*(char*)"? The entire FindPattern func was taken from a tutorial I found, and the same exact function is used widely in the game hacking community, I've used it before on AssaultCube